# Php Deck of cards shuffling and display

Tags: javascript, php, shuffle

I'm trying to do something exactly like this for my client -> [Tarot Card Readings](http://www.free-tarot-reading.net/free)

- The user clicks the deck
- The cards align allowing user to pick 6 cards.
- Once user picked 6 cards he is directed to a page displaying his cards.

My client has 44 cards. I don't have a slight idea on how to even begin such application other than with Php Shuffle (). I'm not looking for a full code but just guidance on how to get started.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question.  What are you having trouble with?  Do you know HTML/CSS?  JavaScript?  What (if any) JavaScript framework are you using?  Maybe you need to ask this as several different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is create two images. One image will be of a deck and then another image will be of a single card. Then what you want to do is create a transition for each image. You can do this all with Jquery. PHP probably won't  help much because PHP doesn't handle manipulating elements as well as JavaScript does.

Jquery.animate will have everything you need to do this. You can also optimize it if you are good with css because css has it's own transition

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.card').animate({
        left: 200px,
        right: 10px
    })
})
```

With CSS:

```
@keyframes card-animate {
    from {left: 20px;}
    to {left: 300px;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
.card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('card.jpg');
    animation-name: card-animate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

EDIT:

You will likely have to create a css class for each card so that they can animate differently.

Or you can create a Jquery animation that adds a few pixels to each element that it animates(so that the user can select a card.) In this case you would have to loop through each element with JavaScript(or more likely JQuery) to toggle the animation. Then you would have to create a click event on each card so that the user can click on the card. Then you will have to store the amount of clicks in a global variable so that each listener can increment it. I would recommend storing the value of the card in an array and then testing for. I would also add the value to your image as an HTML attribute like this.

```
<img class="card" title="aSpades" />

var array = [];

$('.card').click(function(){
    if(array.length < 6){
        array.push($(this).attr('title'));
    } else { // if the user has 6 cards navigate to new page
        window.location.href = "http://www.somesite.fqd/path/to/page"
    }
}
```

You may then have to use PHP and hidden input to pass the array to the next page with a form. It depends on how you are set up. I personally like to use single page apps, and js routers so that I never have to refresh the page, and each page gets stored on the client so that it never has to be reloaded.